# F# List of random numbers concatenated

Tags: f#

Can someone tell me why this works

```
let createRandomList = List.init 9 (fun _ -> randomNumberGenerator.Next(0,9))
let concatRandomList =
    createRandomList
    |> Seq.map string
    |> String.concat ""
```

and this does not?

```
let createConcatRandomList = List.init 9 (fun _ -> randomNumberGenerator.Next(0,9))
    |> Seq.map string
    |> String.concat ""
```

I am getting an "Incomplete value or function definition" on the second code block

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example you need to indent the `|>` to the same level as `List`